# Solana SendTransactionError 0x16

Tags: javascript, solana, solana-web3js, solana-transaction-instruction

I am trying to send a Solana swap transaction using javascript and I am getting `custom program error: 0x16`, I have looked everywhere and the only thing I could find is this list of errors :

https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/ea354ab358021aa08f774e2d4028b33ec56d4180/token/program/src/error.rs#L66

And there is no explanations nor docs that I can find. Has anyone encountered this error before ? or has an explanation on why it happens and how to solve it ?

Here is the full error :

```
SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 5: custom program error: 0x16
```